# Jetbrains Rider Projects compatible with Visual Studio?

Tags: rider, jetbrains-rider

When i work on a new C# Project with Jetbrains Rider is this project compatible with the Visual Studio IDE?

I want to use Jetbrians Rider at work, but my colleagues say that I can use it only if the Rider projects are compatible with the Visual Studio IDE.

So is it compatible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, C# project files are just MSBuild scripts. So, as long as your VS/Rider versions use the compatible MSBuild versions, then the project files can be shared between the two IDEs.

> You can learn how to tell MSBuild versions from posts [like mine](https://halfblood.pro/the-rough-history-of-msbuild-cc72a217fa98).

However, in real world situation Rider/VS compatibility is rather difficult to assert. File bugs to Rider if you find any incompatibility issue,

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/rider